# Why is my database function returning undefined until I reload the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to React/Javascript and while I have a loose grasp at how hooks and async functions work, I am somewhat puzzled as to why I am getting `undefined` from one of my database functions

Here is the database function in question:

```js
async function readFromDB(ID, itemToGrab, type) {
  const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
  const snapshot = await get(
    child(dbRef, `users/` + type + `/${ID}${itemToGrab}`),
  );

  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    return snapshot.val();
  } else {
    console.log("No data available");
  }
}
```

This works fine, as eventually it does get what I need from the database.

Now I use this function here to perform a check on a user. If both database requests return undefined (the provided user has not registered a pet yet), then they are not a pet owner yet, otherwise, they are a pet owner:

```js
async function check() {
  if (
    (await readFromDB(key, '/Pname', type)) === undefined &&
    (await readFromDB(key, '/pets', 'dog-walkers')) === undefined
  ) {
    console.log('user is not actually a owner yet!');
    return 'notOwner';
  } else {
    console.log('user is a owner!');
    return 'owner';
  }
}
```

I then call this check function like this:

```js
const [result, setResult] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    let data = await check();
    setResult(data);
    console.log(data + ' DATA');
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

And then use `result` like this:

```jsx
return (
  <>
    {result === 'owner' ? (
      <p>Owner</p>
    ) : result === 'notOwner' ? (
      <p>notOwner</p>
    ) : (
      <p>Loading Page</p>
    )}
  </>
);
```

When I test the functionality, I make sure that I am using a user who has a pet in their collection, which should set the state to `owner`, however, the state is always set to `notOwner` because the database function always returns `undefined` at first, but when the page is reloaded, it loads the `owner` page correctly.

I though having `async/await` should make the program wait for a response from the database before running the if statement to return a value.

Comment: What are `key` and `type` and where are they defined?

Comment: Those are url parameters I am grabbing from the url of the webpage. I actually managed to fix the issue after adding a return value to the else block of the database function. I had tried this previously but I think I did it incorrectly and it didnt work.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that my database function should have a return value inside the else block. This seems to have worked as now the webpage loads correctly on the initial render. Here is the updated function:

```
async function readFromDB(ID, itemToGrab, type) {
  const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
  const snapshot = await get(
    child(dbRef, `users/` + type + `/${ID}${itemToGrab}`),
  );

  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    return snapshot.val();
  } else {
    console.log("No data available");
    return 'noData'
  }
}
```